# Conditional Formatting of three consecutive cells of the same value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a row of dates in Excel. I need conditional formatting to, if I update continuously three times or more with character `Y`, then those all should be highlighted with colour. If less than three times `Y` consecutively then those cells should not be highlighted. Like this:

```
      12-Dec 13-Dec 14-Dec 15-Dec 16-Dec 17-Dec 18-Dec 19-Dec 20-Dec  
Status         Y      Y      N    **Y      Y      Y**    N      Y
```

I need to colour only 16, 17 and 18th dates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your conditional formats with a formula (see screenshot below).

Conditional formats:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/add-change-find-or-clear-conditional-formats-HA102749062.aspx?CTT=1

Length of string:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/len-lenb-HP005209154.aspx

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but can you Pls check my changes in question.

Answer (score 0):

If Y for the 16th is in G2, please select Columns C:K and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(AND(A1="Y",B1="Y",C1="Y"),AND(B1="Y",C1="Y",D1="Y"),AND(C1="Y",D1="Y",E1="Y"))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your colour, OK, OK.